How do I prevent brush strokes from showing when painting a window casing
I'm painting an oak window casing with off-white semi-gloss paint. I've lightly sanded the wood and plan to apply a coat of Kilz 3 Premium primer and then two coats of the semi-gloss.
I bought a new top of the line brush and want to make sure that my technique minimizes brush strokes appearing in the finish. What's the best way to accomplish this?

Result
I thought that adding my results and takeaways might be helpful to some.

I didn't upgrade the paint because I had already purchased it.
As stated I used a top of the line brush.
I applied the primer coat with a foam roller and primed the edges with a foam brush.
I sanded after the primer coat.
I applied two coats of semi-gloss enamel using a new synthetic bristle brush and did a light sanding (600 grit) after the first coat.
I dampened the bristles before painting (thanks Jimmy Jones) which I think helped with even application.

The keys: Patience; Use plenty of paint with a smooth, long stroke; and don't overwork it.
I also learned that with oak, the grain will almost always show through.


Use a paint sprayer?

Some of your brush marks will be masked/hidden/blended with the wood grain that will show through, as well. Be sure your expectations are reasonable, considering that the wood you are starting with has its own texture.

Side note: that faucet looks like it is extremely close to the casing in the pic. You should really remove it before painting. I know that's daunting if you didn't install it yourself but it's really going to be nearly impossible to work around and get a good result.

@Jimmy James - I did install the faucet and sink and thought about removing the faucet but there is actually just enough room behind it to finish the paint job properly.

Too little for an answer, but I have had good success with a roller. The edges need to be done first, with a brush; the main surfaces then are rolled, getting as close to the edges as possible so that not much of the brushed paint stays visible. It was easier for me to obtain a smooth surface with a roller.

As an aside, is that real oak that you are going to paint white? Tastes differ but it looks really nice.

@Peter - Reinstate Monica - Yes it is! And I understand your point. In another circumstance, in another environment I would probably have just refinished it, but this is what the situation called for.


Apply plenty of paint.

Work it off quickly to leave a uniform film, moving parallel to wood grain in all cases.

Stop messing with it.


You will not avoid all brush marks, but this'll get you close. If that's your primary goal, don't use a brush. Use a foam roller or similar. That, of course, leaves its own texture.

The main thing you need to avoid is 'over-working' the paint.  You should also buy good paint i.e., not big box store or hardware store paint.  Go to a paint store.  Also, get nice brushes and take care of them. They can last many years.
When you apply a brush stroke, the wet paint will always show ridges.  While the paint is still wet, the ridges will spread out and become more even.  If you come over it again while the paint is tacky, you make new ridges that will stay there.  So, part of the trick is having a plan.  Start at the corner with your brush edge aligned with the mitre and draw it to the other corner with as few strokes as possible.  When you get to the other corner, you want the edge of the brush aligned with that mitre.  Continue around to the start but do not touch any of the previous areas again.  Let it fully dry before adding a second coat.  If you are painting more than one casing, this is a good time to move to another one so prep all of them before you paint.  If you get any lines, sand (paint needs to be very dry) and do it again. To clarify, I don't mean down to the wood or even the primer.  Just a light sanding with a medium grit to smooth out the high points/lines. They will tend to get more pronounced with more coats.
After looking at the picture again, a good plan here would be to paint the interior of the opening first.  You might even want to do it in 'lanes' (e.g. back, front, middle) so that you don't overlap with any paint that isn't fully dry.  While that is drying, you can do the trim.  Once both are dry, paint the reveal with a narrow brush.  You can then repeat that cycle as many times as needed.  The point is that you never touch wet painted surface with the brush.
Plan for multiple thin coats.  It gives a much better result and can save you time since you don't need to worry about missed spots. That's important for this kind of thing since you really want to avoid brushing over paint that's not completely dry.
I'm assuming this is latex or acrylic paint here. One thing that I find helps with paint brushes is to wet the brush before starting. You don't want it dripping, just not dry. Then clean the brush regularly so that it isn't fouled with tacky or dry paint.  When washing, never push the paint up towards the handle, always away.  When painting, try to avoid getting paint in the upper half (near the handle) of the bristles.  It's very hard to get out and can ruin the brush.

I like the tip about slightly wetting the brush. I think it helps get even paint distribution across the brush and smoother application.

This, if you insist on using a brush. Foam roller, if it 100% cannot have brush stokes.

If you want things really smooth:
After primer has dried, I sand lightly with 600 or 800 grit.
Then apply 2 coats of paint. Painting with the grain.
I then give things a final coat with paint thinned slightly.
Put plastic or a good drop cloth under the frame to catch drips.
This can take longer, but worth it.

TL;DR

High quality alkyd paint
High quality brush
Patience


If your goal is to practically eliminate brush marks then you need to use a paint which supports your goals.
I've heard that watering it down a little helps the paint exhibit some self-leveling properties.
Gently sanding between coats should help as well.
Video - I Found the Best Hybrid Alkyd Paint! Side by Side Test of the Most Popular Brands

Thanks for the good tips. I have patience but as I've gotten older (81) sometimes I'm not as steady with those hard to reach places like this one, over the sink. But the good news is, I can still do it!

Side by Side Test of the Most Popular Brands that don't cost $150 a gallon like F&B does? Forget brush strokes, if you want it 'burnished' and can still see the grain of the wood, then use F&B's system. If that's not what you're after, then use any paint and any roller.

@Mazura What's F&B?

https://www.farrow-ball.com/us/
